# remove all applied CSS in all element of under particular div

Tags: jquery, css

there is too many CSS included like bootstrap and other
an in on div i want to make it complete clean CSS, 
remove all applied CSS in all element of under particular div

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
`$('#element *').removeAttr('style')` to remove all styles of elements within the enclosed element.
Or use 
`$('#element').children().removeAttr('style')` to remove styles of the children of the enclosed element.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support old browsers, you may use `initial` value for each property like this:

```
/* short version
   all: initial; */

color: initial;
font-weight: initial;
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/0jgmfqx8/

More on `all` property: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/